# How can I display only cars with 5 seats?

Tags: c++, sorting

How can I make the program display only cars that have 5 seats, for now no matter what, it shows all cars that I write infos about them, for example if I write in the console that there are 3 cars and give information about them and say that one has 2 seats and the others have 5 after I run the program it still displays all 3 of them. Any idea of how can I display only cars with 5 seats? Can I somehow use the quicksort() function ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Car
{
    int no_seats;
    int year;
    char brand[20];
    char color[20];
    float horse_power;
};

void read_cars(Car C[], int &n)
{
    int i;
    cout << "Number of parked cars "; cin >> n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {  
       cout << "Brand " ; cin >> M[i].brand;
       cout << "The year it was made in " ; cin >> M[i].year;
       cout << "Color " ; cin >> M[i].color;
       cout << "Power " ; cin >> M[i].horse_power;  
       cout << "Number of seats " ; cin >> M[i].no_seats;
    }  

}

void display_cars(Car C[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
       cout << "Brand " ; cout << M[i].brand << endl;
       cout << "The year it was made in " ; cout << M[i].year << endl;
       cout << "Color " ; cout << M[i].color << endl;
       cout << "Power " ; cout << M[i].horse_power << endl; 
       cout << "Number of seats " ; cout << M[i].no_seats << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    Car C[50];
    int n;

    read_cars(M, n);
    display_cars(M, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you have an "off by one" error in your loops.   Array indexing starts at ZERO in C++ i.e. `a[0]` is the first element of an array `a`.   Looping from `1` to `n` (if `n` is the number of elements in the array) will go one past the end of the array, and cause undefined behaviour.   Entering a value of `50` for `n` in your code will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition in the loop:

```
void display_cars(Car C[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
       if(M[i].no_seats == 5)        //     <-   like this
       {
          cout << "Brand " ; cout << M[i].brand << endl;
          cout << "The year it was made in " ; cout << M[i].year << endl;
          cout << "Color " ; cout << M[i].color << endl;
          cout << "Power " ; cout << M[i].horse_power << endl; 
          cout << "Number of seats " ; cout << M[i].no_seats << endl;
       }
    }
}
```

Other notes:

- Your `n` can only go up to `49` - remember that. That also means that you are wasting an element at `M[0]` (yes arrays are zero based in C++).
- Prefer to use `std::vector<Car> C` over an array of fixed size. A `std::vector` grows as you `push_back` more and more elements into it - and it keeps track of the number of contained elements, so you do not need to pass the size of the vector around. `C.size()` would tell you the number of elements.

```
void display_cars(const std::vector<Car>& C)
{
    std::cout << "There are " << C.size() << " cars in the vector\n";

    for(const Car& a_car : C)    // a range based for-loop
    {
        if(a_car.no_seats == 5)  // a_car will be a reference to each car in the loop
        {
            // use "a_car" to display info about one particular car
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think an if statement was all I needed, I mean I tried doing so but I think I did it in the main and it didn't work. Thank you again for help :))